# What namespace does CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifierOptions live in?

Tags: namespaces, sitecore

Using Sitecore 9.1.1 I am try to connect to my xconnect server with a console app using the sample code found here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create,-retrieve,-and-search-contact-and-interaction-data.html

I have used NuGet (Sitecore MyGet) to retrieve the libraries that are being used:

```
using Sitecore.XConnect;   
using Sitecore.XConnect.Client;   
using Sitecore.XConnect.Schema; 
using System;   
using System.Threading.Tasks;   
using Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi;  
using Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web;  
using Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web;
```

However....

With in Visual Studio 2019 **CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifierOptions** and **CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifier** are red-lined with "namespace could not be found, are you missing assembly.."

I have googled and cannot find which libraries these classes live in. Can someone tell me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that these two classes have been renamed in Sitecore 9.1.1. Namespace Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web:

CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifierOptions = Certificate**Http**ClientHandlerModifierOptions

CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifier = Certificate**Http**ClientHandlerModifier